How do I drop duplicates within groups that were collected within 60min of one another?
I have camera trap data where I want to remove potentially duplicated animal detections. I am setting the interval as 60min (1 hour) so that any individual detected of the same species at the same camera is the same individual if it is detected again within <60min. My data is collected at multiple blocks with multiple sites within a block.
#Data example:
Block<-c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b") #2 block
Site<-c("p1","p1","p2","p2","p2","p1","p1","p1","p2","p2") #two sites
Species<-c("c","c","c","c","e","d","d","c","c","c")
datetime<-c("2021-03-29 05:45:00","2021-03-29 06:40:00","2021-03-30 05:45:00","2021-03-30 07:45:00","2021-03-29 09:45:00","2021-03-29 05:45:00","2021-03-29 05:55:00","2021-03-29 08:45:00","2021-03-29 10:45:00","2021-03-30 10:59:00")
df<-data.frame(Block, Site, Species, datetime)

#what I want for the output: 

   Block Site Species            datetime
1      a   p1       c 2021-03-29 05:45:00
2      a   p2       c 2021-03-30 05:45:00
3      a   p2       c 2021-03-30 07:45:00
4      a   p2       e 2021-03-29 09:45:00
5      b   p1       d 2021-03-29 05:45:00
6      b   p1       c 2021-03-29 08:45:00
7      b   p2       c 2021-03-29 10:45:00
8      b   p2       c 2021-03-30 10:59:00

The tricky part, at least for me, is I need to remove duplicates of Block/Site/Species that appear within 1 hour of one another (I can't just say keep the first within in hour period of the day).
Thank you for your help.

If you have matching block, site and species and times of 5:45, 6:30, 7:15 do you want to keep the first and last one, or would you consider all 3 to be the same individual?

Why remove row 10, it's one day later?

user2554330: great question. I would consider all three to be the same individual

Andre Wildberg, thanks for the catch. I have fixed the dataset

What if you had one at 5, another at 5:45, and another at 6:30? Still same individual?

Jon Spring - yes, I would consider them the same individuals

Using diff and then filter by set intv
library(dplyr)

intv <- 60

df %>% 
  mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime)) %>% 
  arrange(Block, Site, Species, datetime) %>% 
  filter(c(intv + 1, diff(datetime, units="mins")) > intv, 
         .by = c(Block, Site, Species))
  Block Site Species            datetime
1     a   p1       c 2021-03-29 05:45:00
2     a   p2       c 2021-03-30 05:45:00
3     a   p2       c 2021-03-30 07:45:00
4     a   p2       e 2021-03-29 09:45:00
5     b   p1       c 2021-03-29 08:45:00
6     b   p1       d 2021-03-29 05:45:00
7     b   p2       c 2021-03-29 10:45:00
8     b   p2       c 2021-03-30 10:59:00


Perfect. Thank you very much!
